# Angular Route Param Values Not Binding with ngClass Ternary

Tags: angular, routes, ternary

My return value from my html ternary, **previewForm.value['joint_application']** is binding the incorrect string output within **form-page.component.html**. User is expected to navigate back from this preview page to home page to edit this value in another form which populates the URL with params which are then processed by previewForm

previewForm.value['joint_application'] takes the parameters from the URL is parsed to find whether the params is true or false then displays it accordingly on the html.

This ternary doesnt seem to alternate accordingly based on the URL:

```
{{ previewForm.value['joint_application'] ? 'Me & My Partner': 'Just Me' }}
```

So if joint_application=true in the URL I expect 'Me & My Partner', however I only get 'Just Me'

However this does alternate from true and false accordingly

```
{{ previewForm.value['joint_application'] }}
```

My typical URL would be:

http://localhost:4200/quote-form;joint_application=true

Which is passed from my home page to this quote-form page via this route:

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'quote-form', component: FormPageComponent },
]
```

**form-page.component.ts**

```
export class FormPageComponent implements OnInit {
    public previewForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ){ }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.previewParamValues()
    }

    previewParamValues() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.previewForm = this.fb.group({
                joint_application: params.joint_application,
            });
        })
    }
```

**form-page.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="previewForm">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <h6 small ><b>Quotes For: &nbsp;</b></h6>
        <h6 small>{{ previewForm.value['joint_application'] ? 'Me & My Partner': 'Just Me' }}</h6>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a form control instead of just passing the value when creating a form group.

```js
previewParamValues() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.previewForm = this.fb.group({
      //                 <---- create control here
      joint_application: this.fb.control(params.joint_application),
    });
  })
}
```

And a word of warning - be careful to convert your param value into a boolean. If you param ever looks like `joint_application=false`, I suspect you would just get the string value `"false"`, which is still truthy.

Instead, you should create your form control using a boolean value:

Angular <= 8

```js
this.fb.control(!!params.joint_application && 
  params.joint_application.toLowerCase() === 'true')
```

Angular >= 9

```js
this.fb.control(params.joint_application?.toLowerCase() === 'true')
```

EDIT

The "bang bang" operator `!!` isn't *strictly* necessary in the <= v8 version, unless you care about comparing against strict boolean types.

Here's a rather trivial example:

```js
const value = null;

const result1 = value && value === 'true';
const result2 = !!value && value === 'true';

const check1 = result1 === false;
const check2 = result2 === false;

console.log("(value && value === 'true') === false");
console.log(check1);
console.log("(!!value && value === 'true') === false");
console.log(check2);
```

And thinking about it, the equivalent to this in the >= v9 version would be

```js
this.fb.control(params.joint_application?.toLowerCase() === 'true' || false)
```

Comment: I am unable to compile adding the line this.fb.control(params.joint_application?.toLowerCase() === 'true').
A colon or expression is expected

Comment: Might be because you're on an older version of Angular. I've edited my second code block

Comment: That did the fix! thank you! Are you using angular 9? I'm using 8. Do you mind leaving the 9 fix in your post?

Comment: Why is the !! necessary, can that be omitted to receive the same results?

Comment: The !! isn't strictly necessary, I'm just a sucker for strict types. The !! will always return a boolean, so if `params.joint_application` is null, then `false` will be returned rather than `null`. If you're just performing "falsy" checks downstream, this doesn't matter, but it does matter if you're comparing strict boolean values.

Comment: And yes, I'm on V9 - when the world was finally introduced to optional chaining. Now I can barely contain my excitement and I use it whenever possible.

Comment: I've added a !! demo to my answer, to fully demonstrate what I'm talking about. Generally it doesn't make a difference because we're all lazy and just do `!condition` rather than `condition === false`.